# eglCreateWindowSurface() can only be called with an instance of Surface, SurfaceView, SurfaceTexture or SurfaceHolder

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, surfaceview

I am using RecordableSurfaceView
https://github.com/spaceLenny/recordablesurfaceview/blob/master/recordablesurfaceview/src/main/java/com/uncorkedstudios/android/view/recordablesurfaceview/RecordableSurfaceView.java

For android 6, (api 23) I get this error. Is there a way to fix this?

```
eglCreateWindowSurface() can only be called with an instance of Surface, SurfaceView, SurfaceTexture or SurfaceHolder at the moment, this will be fixed later.
.RecordableSurfaceView
```

The potential code segment.

```
 mEGLSurface = EGL14
                .eglCreateWindowSurface(mEGLDisplay, eglConfig, RecordableSurfaceView.this,
                        surfaceAttribs, 0);
        EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(mEGLDisplay, mEGLSurface, mEGLSurface, mEGLContext);

        // guarantee to only report surface as created once GL context
        // associated with the surface has been created, and call on the GL thread
        // NOT the main thread but BEFORE the codec surface is attached to the GL context
        if (mRendererCallbacksWeakReference != null
                && mRendererCallbacksWeakReference.get() != null) {

            mRendererCallbacksWeakReference.get().onSurfaceCreated();

        }

        mEGLSurfaceMedia = EGL14
                .eglCreateWindowSurface(mEGLDisplay, eglConfig, mSurface,
                        surfaceAttribs, 0);

        GLES20.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

write a null check for this mEGLSurface and done
`(mEGLSurface != null)`

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet of `RecordableSurfaceView` the second call to `eglCreateWindowSurface` passes in a `mSurface` variable which is initialized in `doSetup` via:

```java
mSurface = MediaCodec.createPersistentInputSurface();
```

I would guess that your codec doesn't support this function and it's somehow returning null, which is causing the exception you see. Or perhaps it's being used by more than one codec or recorder instance?

The only other somewhat related question on SO I could find is: [MediaCodec's Persistent Input Surface unsupported by Camera2 Session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582437/mediacodecs-persistent-input-surface-unsupported-by-camera2-session)

Can you at least clarify from the stack trace where in the library it's crashing? In other words, from which call of `eglCreateWindowSurface`?